# Scatter plot time and symbols

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time, scatter-plot

I have searched for an answer to my problem without success. 
I have a dataset that looks similar to this

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
c("344", "73", "73", "71", "344", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
c(7, 15, 6, 9, 20, 12, 4, 5, 2, 0),
c(2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
))
names(df) <- c("number", "code", "time_1", "time_2")
```

The dataset contains items (variable "code" i.e. all rows with the same code number is regarding the same item) and times from a starting point (time_1 and time_2). Variable time_1 contains different times for different rows but variable time_2 contains the same time for each item (i.e. each row with the same code has the same time from starting point in time_2).

I would like to plot the times for each item on the same row. I have tried the following code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(time_1, code)) +
+   geom_point(size=2, col="steelblue") + 
+   theme_bw() +
+   labs(x="Time from start", y="Code")
```

I have two problems with the code:

First - I would like to be able to sort all rows after time_1 so the x-axis is from 0 to 20. But this does not seem to be working since the time 7 for item 344 comes after time 20 in the plot but not in the table.

Second - I would also like to be able to plot both time_1 and time_2 for each item in the same plot and that all data from the variable time_2 is indicated with another symbol (for example a triangle) in the scatterplot.

Any suggestions that might help me?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? I had to change the datatypes because the data frame was a set up a little funky. If you use the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  number =  c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
  code = c("344", "73", "73", "71", "344", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
  time1 = c(7, 15, 6, 9, 20, 12, 4, 5, 2, 0),
  time2 = c(2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
  )
```

You will not have to change any of the datatypes and can skip to the `dplyr` chain:

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df$code <- as.factor(df$code)
df$time_1 <- as.integer(df$time_1)
df$time_2 <- as.integer(df$time_2)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -c(code, number)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, code, shape = key)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, col = "steelblue") +
  labs(x = "Time from start", y = "Code") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(
  c("3", "3", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "4", "4"),
  c("344", "73", "73", "71", "344", "72", "21", "27", "42", "43"),
  c(7, 15, 6, 9, 20, 12, 4, 5, 2, 0),
  c(2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3)
), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Definitely in the right direction. Is it possible to treat the "code" numbers as nominals? Since they only represent an ID for the sample.

Comment: Great. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.